# Filtering records in a Napili Community Page?

Tags: customer-community, napili, filters, record

I have a checkbox: **Archive** on a Custom object which gets checked on the records which were two hours old. I wanted to pull these records in a separate tab: **Archived Records** in a community page. I can see a standard component **Record List** which pulls all the records irrespective of any filters. How can I create/customize a filter to display only **Archive** checkbox checked-in records?

Answer (score 1):

In order to apply your custom filter, you will most likely have to create a custom lightning component with a server side controller to fetch your custom object records.

[The Lightning Component Developer Guide : Working with Salesforce Records](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/apex_records.htm)

has this well documented so I wont post a detailed explanation.

Example server side controller:

```
public with sharing class potatocontroller { 

    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<potato__c> getPotatos() {
        List<potato__c> potatos = new List<potato__c>();
        potatos = [Select ID, Name from potato__c WHERE checker__c=true];
        return potatos;
    }
}
```

above, I am  filtering on records that are 'checked'.

then, you will have to use a client side controller to invoke your @AuraEnabled apex class:

```
({
    getpotatos: function(cmp){
        var action = cmp.get("c.getPotatos");
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                cmp.set("v.potatos", response.getReturnValue());
            }
        });
     $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },

})
```

and render your records in your component:

```
<aura:component controller="potatocontroller" implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
    <aura:attribute name="potatos" type="c.potato__c[]"/>

    <ui:button label="Get potatos" press="{!c.getpotatos}"/>

    <aura:iteration var="potato" items="{!v.potatos}">
        <p>{!potato.Name} : {!potato.Id}</p>
    </aura:iteration>

</aura:component>
```

when working with custom objects, you must add the namespace prior to the object type.

Additionally, you might want to modify the styling in your design file.

Comment: But there should be some way or other to get to the filter criteria in the standard **Record List** component right?

Comment: like a permanent filter? because i know that OOTB, you can change it (users as well)

Comment: if you want the component to ONLY show based on that filter, you will have to go custom,  as far as I am concerned

Comment: Just realized: We can create a new **List View** on the custom object of the standard Salesforce Classic with the necessary filter criteria, which shows up in the **Record List** community component.